# Javadoc not being used within NetBeans Gradle Build

Tags: netbeans, gradle, rx-java

I have a gradle project in netbeans.  I defined the dependency to RxJava in the build file and everything went as expected there.  Coding work fines, etc.

The problem is that it does not use the javadoc for RxJava from within the IDE (NetBeans).

I checked and the javadoc jar is cached.  It is just not being used.  I've went through and tried to find an option to link it in the IDE but could not find one.

I've done some searching and the things I've found say that when you specify a dependency from a remote location everything is supposed to sync up automatically.

Hopefully, it's something simple that I'm missing.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you using this plugin http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/44510/gradle-support?

Comment: I am using 1.3.8.1 which I believe is the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to the script:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea{
    module{
        downloadJavadoc=true
    }
}
```

Then refresh the project and check if the javadoc is being used.

Comment: This is only a comment (troubleshooting suggestion), not an actual answer :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Javadoc from sources is preferred over downloaded Javadoc, but is not something that can be served and viewed in a browser as it is not HTML. The issue [has been opened](https://github.com/kelemen/netbeans-gradle-project/issues/359) since Sep 23, 2017 but has not been addressed yet.